# Splitting an object in R

Tags: r, object, split

I would like to split an object in R according to the suffixes of the barcodes it contains. These end in '-n' where n is a number from 1 to 6. e.g. AAACCGTGCCCTCA-1, GAACCGTGCCCTCA-2, CATGCGTGCCCTCA-5, etc. I would like all the corresponding information about each barcode to be split accordingly as well. Here is some example code of an object, cds.

```
class(cds)
[1] "CellDataSet"
attr(,"package")
[1] "monocle"

split(cds, cds$barcode)
#not by individual barcodes, but by groups of those ending '-1', '-2',...,'-6'. So 6 new objects in total
```

Many thanks!

Abigail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split does not work because you need to subset based on the columns. I am not sure if there is a split method defined for this class. You can try the following:

First to get something like your example:

```
library(monocle)
library(HSMMSingleCell)
library(Biostrings)

cds = load_HSMM()

class(cds)
[1] "CellDataSet"
attr(,"package")
[1] "monocle"

dim(cds)
Features  Samples 
   47192      271
```

And to create a barcode for every sample:

```
bar = paste(names(oligonucleotideFrequency(DNAString("NNNNN"),5))[1:ncol(cds)],
sample(1:6,ncol(cds),replace=TRUE),sep="-")

head(bar)
[1] "AAAAA-3" "AAAAC-6" "AAAAG-5" "AAAAT-1" "AAACA-5" "AAACC-5"
```

Now we get the group, which is the suffix 1-6 :

```
cds$barcodes= bar
grp = sub("[A-Z]*[-]","",cds$barcodes)
```

To get one subset, for example, those will "-1", you can just do:

```
group1 = cds[,grp==1]
dim(group1)
Features  Samples 
   47192       46 
head(group1$barcodes)
[1] "AAAAT-1" "AACGA-1" "AAGCG-1" "AAGGG-1" "AAGTA-1" "AATAG-1"
```

To get your 6 groups, you can do the below, but check whether your machine has the memory to accommodate this!

```
subset_obj = lapply(unique(grp),function(i){
cds[,grp==i]
})
names(subset_obj) = unique(grp)
```

Comment: Thanks StupidWolf! Do you know if, instead of splitting this object, I can instead apply different functions selectively to a subset of the data according to the different barcode groups? For example, if I wanted to just use the function 'plot_genes_in_pseudotime()' on each barcode group, from 1-6, separately.

Comment: Hi @Abigail575, you would do something like this, my_genes <- row.names(subset(fData(cds), gene_short_name %in% c("CDK1", "MEF2C", "MYH3"))) ;  cds_subset <- cds[my_genes,grp==1] ; plot_genes_in_pseudotime(cds_subset, color_by = "Hours")

Comment: The plot is based on ggplot2, so you can research on how to combine plots or have the dimensions altered..

Comment: Hi StupidWolf! I was wondering if perhaps you know why I receive an error message here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68178479/error-message-when-using-getgeosuppfiles-function Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sub` to remove the `-\\d+` and split the 'cds' based on that

```
split(cds, sub("-\\d+$", "", cds$barcode))
```

Comment: Thank you! I got the following error: Warning message:
In split.default(cds, sub("-\\d+$", "", cds$barcode)) :
  data length is not a multiple of split variable                                                     Does this mean the number of barcodes ending -1 to -6 is not the same? Also, what would the script be if I want to split the cds based on the number at the end of each barcode, but to keep the barcodes as they are? Thanks!

Comment: i.e. without removing the numbers at the end

Comment: Can you try `split(cds$barcode, sub("-\\d+$", "", cds$barcode))`